# Re-use of issue ID's in Jira

Tags: jira

I was wondering if it is possible to create a new Jira issue that has the ID of a previously deleted issue. It seems like once you delete an issue in Jira, its ID number is unusable forever. Am I wrong?

Comment: What is referred to an issue ID in this discussion is in fact the issue *key* which changes when an issue is moved to a different JIRA project. There is also a numeric id for each issue which is constant. Best not to bend the tool where it isn't meant to bend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JIRA's API this is not possible since, well, the ID should be *unique* within a project also across time.

Depending on how desperate you are, you can modify the database field `project.pcounter` to point to the wanted ID (you will not run into duplicate ID problems doing so - if `pcounter` contains an ID already taken, JIRA will iterate to the next available one).

This will also require a restart of JIRA, so for one issue this is quite expensive.

For more information, see the respective [article in the Atlassian Knowledge Base](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=211649701)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Jira IDs are not reusable. Which is a good thing, because people may refer to a Jira issue, even a deleted one, by number in the future. Besides, numbers are cheap.